# Is there a way to tell how close you are to getting a badge?

Tags: achievements, animal-crossing-new-leaf

For example,  you need to dive and catch 500 sea creatures to get the gold badge from Phineas.  I have now been keeping track of how many I have caught,  but I didn't do that from the beginning.  Is there a way to see how far you are or how many you have done to see exactly how many more I need?  For this badge and all other badges.

Answer (score -1):

No, no there isn't. (It would be a wonderful add to the game though)

Fish Encyclopedia (Maybe)

However, it's been far too long since i've even touched this game. Maybe the Fish Encyclopedia will tell you in total for fish caught.